# Fish Carcass Identification

Tags: species-identification

Can anyone identify the species of this fish carcass?

This photo was taken in Brooklyn, NY. The fish would have presumably been in Gravesend Bay.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The large lozenge-shaped scales suggest me it could be some [sturgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon) species. The location is compatible with what Wikipedia says:

> In North America, they range along the Atlantic Coast from the Gulf of Mexico to Newfoundland [...]

Specialists may be able to refine a little more the identification, based on location and visible features.

Comment: I asked on reddit too and got the same answer, so I think you’re right. Thanks!